# Dynamic Job Data using Quartz

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

When my process gets a message, it needs to start a timer and execute some logic in X seconds. These jobs need to be stored in a JDBC store, which as far as I can tell may be irrelevant to this question.

Based on what I've read, I should be able to assign a JobDataMap with different values for similar properties to a single Job class, but I'm unable to find any documentation or examples to back this use-case. Perhaps my Google-fu is weak.

Does that make sense? Have one Job class and somehow store a JobDataMap to populate that Job class and run it on a per-message basis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`org.quartz.Trigger` has both `getJobDataMap()` (which will `new` up one if necessary) and  `setJobDataMap()` to get the trigger's [JobDataMap](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/JobDataMap.html).

The simplest usage would be:

```
Trigger t = new SimpleTrigger(...);
t.getJobDataMap().put("foo", "bar");
```

To init with an existing Map of values:

```
Map data = new HashMap();
data.put("foo", "bar");

t.setJobDataMap(new JobDataMap(data));
```

To get the data when your job executes

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
{
   String fooValue = context.getMergedJobDataMap().get("foo");
}
```

---

[Documentation on JobDataMap](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-03.html#TutorialLesson3-JobDataMap) in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Hi cansando (you speak spanish???). 
I going to give you my example of Quartz.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
        try {

            Scheduler sched;
            sched = schedFact.getScheduler();

            sched.start();

            JobDetail jobd = new JobDetail("instruccion", "instrucciones",
                    Mensaje.class);

//          TriggerExample trigger = new TriggerExample("instruccion",
//                  "instrucciones");

            jobd.setRequestsRecovery(true);
            SimpleTrigger trigger2 = new SimpleTrigger("lanzador principal", "lanzadores", "instruccion","instrucciones" , Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), null, 100, 10000);

            trigger2.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);
            sched.scheduleJob(jobd, trigger2);

            //      
            // }
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };


public class Mensaje implements Job {


    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Hola Mundo");

    }

}


public class TriggerExample extends Trigger {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4926331843008217753L;

    Date fechaAEjecutar;


    public TriggerExample(){

        super();
    }

    public TriggerExample(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    public TriggerExample(String name, String group){
        super(name, group);
    }

    public TriggerExample(String name, String group,String jobname, String jobgroup){
        super(name,group,jobname,jobgroup);
    }



    @Override
    public Date computeFirstFireTime(Calendar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int executionComplete(JobExecutionContext arg0,
            JobExecutionException arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getEndTime() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getFinalFireTime() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getFireTimeAfter(Date arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getNextFireTime() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getPreviousFireTime() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getStartTime() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mayFireAgain() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEndTime(Date arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setStartTime(Date arg0) {
        this.fechaAEjecutar = arg0;
        System.out.println("Cargue la fecha el data con valor\n");
        System.out.println(this.fechaAEjecutar.getTime());

    }

    @Override
    public void triggered(Calendar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void updateAfterMisfire(Calendar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void updateWithNewCalendar(Calendar arg0, long arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean validateMisfireInstruction(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

In this line             SimpleTrigger trigger2 = new SimpleTrigger("lanzador principal", "lanzadores", "instruccion","instrucciones" , Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), null, 100, 10000);

can you set the time to execute and repeat.