# Quartz capabilities

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am trying to create a Quartz scheduler using Java which will be able to call an API and pass in data.

I am totally new to Quartz but now I understand the Job concept and how to create one.  I understand the trigger concept and how to trigger one
and I understand how the scheduler works.

What I am having difficult with is how can I pass in the information which is required to be passed to the API.  I have an example of an API being called and the data is entered into the DB but the information has been hard coded into the class be passed into the JobDetails.

Ie. the user passes a message to the system which needs to be sent to the user in 12 hours and not before, so what i was planning was create a Job and a trigger in to set the execute time to 12 hours.  How to do i pass the message into the scheduler?  Where should this message be stored?  Is what I am trying to do possible?  Have i misunderstood what Quartz is capable of doing?

Thank you for your time.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [JobDataMap](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/JobDataMap.html). If you are creating a new job for each user action you can store the message in there which will be available during the execution.

> JobDataMap Holds state information for Job instances.
>
> JobDataMap instances are stored once when the Job is added to a scheduler. They are also re-persisted after every execution of jobs annotated with @PersistJobDataAfterExecution.
>
> JobDataMap instances can also be stored with a Trigger. This can be useful in the case where you have a Job that is stored in the scheduler for regular/repeated use by multiple Triggers, yet with each independent triggering, you want to supply the Job with different data inputs.
>
> The JobExecutionContext passed to a Job at execution time also contains a convenience JobDataMap that is the result of merging the contents of the trigger's JobDataMap (if any) over the Job's JobDataMap (if any).

In case you have a single job but for each user action you are creating a new trigger, you can follow the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344374/dynamic-job-data-using-quartz).

Third option will be, for each user action, persist the message and time to send email to the database. Have a job that runs periodically and scans through database for eligible records for which email has to be sent

Comment: Thank you so much for this information.  This is exactly what I needed to resolve this issue.